# Default visibility settings on facebook publish permissions dialog

Tags: facebook, post, permissions, facebook-login

When asking a user for publish_actions permission in my facebook apps, facebook asks the user for the level of visibility fir these posts. [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQGqU.png).
However, for each app I get a different level set as the default in this dialog, in some "public" is set, some "friends" and some "only me".
I know I can change these in the user's app settings , but how can this default level be controlled from the app itself (seeing as I would like to ask for public permission by default ).
I dont mind the user selecting a different level in the dialog, but how is the default level set?
Any ideas will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your app dashboard, go to `App Details`, section `App Center Listed Platforms`.
Click on `Configure App Center Permissions`, select `Default Activity Privacy`, and `Save` the setting.

(Your app does not need to be listed in App Center, nor do you need to submit your App Details for review for this setting to take effect.)

**Edit:** It seems they removed this setting, so now it is totally up to the user to select their desired privacy setting when they are asked for `publish_actions` permission; suggesting a default value does not seem possible any more.

Comment: CBroe, Thank you!!!! that was awesome. I dont know how I missed this? [details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/tutorial)

Comment: Was this moved since this answer been written? Can't find it there.

Comment: @shaharsol: Yes, it seems they removed this setting, so now it is totally up to the user to select their desired privacy setting when they are asked for `publish_actions` permission; suggesting a default value does not seem possible any more.

Answer (score 0):

As @CBroe pointed out it can be set in the app center permissions on the app dashboard.
[details here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/tutorial)